# How can I make two chicken mothers eat peacefully?

Tags: behavior, chickens

Two of my chickens just hatched their eggs and I noticed since then that whenever I call them to give all of them food, two of the chicken mothers start fighting for where to eat.

I didn't worry until now because I usually notice this whenever two of my chickens hatch their eggs around the same period. I solved this problem by spreading the food, the chicken mothers will then go to two locations and stop fighting.

However, doing that still doesn't solve the problem of these two. No matter how far I spread the food, they will fight to eat at the same spot.

- What is the cause of their fight?
- How can I stop it and make them eat peacefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is any way of feeding them in separately enclosed places, this would be the easiest solution to begin with. Is it possible to keep one locked in the coop and allow one out to start feeding first before letting the second one out.

Try and observe which is the more aggressive of the two mothers and feed her first. By reinforcing the natural pecking order, it may help alleviate squabbles.

If you scatter the food into two areas, as opposed to over a large general area and place one chicken in each area with a reasonable gap between the two areas, it will make each chicken more reluctant to leave her food to go chase the other chicken from another pile of food, as she risks losing her food pile.

If possible stand between them while they eat, you can be a human fence and referee in the middle of their feeding escapades. You can use your voice to praise or scold them, you seem to have a close relationship with your chickens and  they will get the idea of approval and disapproval from you. Whilst this, on it's own would have little effect, it will improve your communication with them and increase your overall bond. As mentioned in an [answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/1319/87) to [How do I make my chicken overcome his fears?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-do-i-make-my-chicken-overcome-his-fears), animals respond to how they are handled.

Another thing is to try feeding them more regularly or providing more feed. If they are going a bit hungry this will increase the likelihood of squabbling over food.

Answer (score 4):

Chickens will always squabble, it is part of their mental need for a pecking order. Some particular breeds are notorious for being especially nasty, so if your two hens are different breeds, you might want to look into that. You only need to worry if the pecking is excessive, for example, bald spots forming, blood being drawn. A peck here and there and a small squabble now and then is natural, though.

But as the other answers say, spreading the food out, feeding abundantly, or confining while feeding will help the issue, but they will always squabble at least a little.